# In D&D 4E, Changelings can keep other forms when sleeping?

Tags: dnd-4e

Well, I did not find anywhere a rule against it. 
Am I right in assuming that they can maintain their alternate form when they sleep?

Comment: This realydeoends in if you consider being asleep as being unconcious

Comment: I removed the "Changeling" tag as I am pretty certain it is a tag for White Wolf's Changeling series of games and not the D&D race.

Comment: I convinced a dm to allow me to play as a changling once... he swore he would never do it again.

Answer (score 15):

**Yes.**  The power that allows a changeling to disguise themselves states:

> The new form lasts until you change form again.

[image]

The only thing that would supersede the wording of the power is the unconscious condition, but there is nothing there that indicates that effects end.

> [**Unconscious**](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=146)
>
> While a creature is unconscious, it is helpless, it can’t take actions, and it takes a -5 penalty to all defenses. It also can’t flank and is unaware of its surroundings. When a creature is subjected to this condition, it falls prone, if possible. See also helpless and prone.

If you're still not convinced, take a look at the glossary entry for [Polymorph](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=76):

> Death Ends: Polymorph effects end immediately on a creature that dies.

Nothing there about being unconscious either.

There's also a discussion [here](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/27325993/Duration_of_Powers_and_Going_Unconscious) that goes into more detail and covers other effects (Auras, conjurations, marks, stances, etc).

Comment: Good to know... (Chuckles evilly) But in all seriousness, this is exactly how I interpreted it. I would argue they would only lose their form upon death as a player, and that's just what I'd rule as a DM.

Comment: Another hint is that there's no sustain entry, which implies that the Changeling doesn't have to put any effort into holding a form, only to change it.

Comment: Stances don't have a sustain entry, but specifically say that you lose the stance when you fall unconscious.